# Converting 2D array to string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to convert a 2D array into string in C#. My 2D array is something like this :

```
i=1;
string[][] array = new string[i][];
             array[i][0] = m;
             array[i][1] = n;
             array[i][2] = o;
             array[i][3] = p;
             array[i][4] = q;
             array[i][5] = r;
             array[i][6] = s;
```

and I want to print m n o p q r s t ... whenever a "i" value is selected by an function or method..

Answer (score 1):

This kind of 2D array is an array of arrays (as opposed to a 2D array "proper", which would be `string[,]`). You can take an entire row from this array, and pass it to `string.Join`, like this:

```
var str = string.Join(" ", array[i]);
```

Note that you cannot do this trick with a "proper" 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

So for any given `i`, you're just trying to basically flatten a single-dimension array.

There's a method called [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) that will do exactly that (flatten an array, separating each element with a "separator" of your choice - a space in this case):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", array[i]));
```